# Function not pointing to the updated value of state variable using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently refactoring a react app from setState to hooks. I can't understand why the state variables aren't changed. Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Hook() {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", logNum);
    }, []);

    const logNum = () => {
        console.log(num);
    }
    const handleToggle = () => {
        if (num == 1) {
            console.log('setting num to 2');
            setNum(2);
        } else {
            console.log('setting num to 1');
            setNum(1);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleToggle}>TOGGLE BOOL</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Hook;
```

When i click the button, I was expecting the output to be something like:

```
// 1
// setting num to 2
// 2
// setting num to 1
// 1
```

But the output look like this:

[image]

Why is the updated num variable not logged?
Shouldn't the logNum() function always point to the current value of the state?

Comment: For a `console.log()` to appear within your console, you'll need to place it or reference it with the function's `return ()` statement. And that's why whatever you've `console.log`ged within `handleToggle` is returned.

Comment: @mwamiTovi um ... nope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why effect dependencies have to be *exhaustive*.  [Don't lie about dependencies](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies).

`logNum` closures over `num`, so on every rerender there is a new `num` variable containing the new value, and a new `logNum` function logging that value. Your effect however gets initialized only once, thus it only knows the first `logNum`. Therefore, you have to add `logNum` as a dependency, so that the effect gets updated whenever `num` and thus `logNum` changes:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", logNum);
}, [logNum]);
```

You'll notice that your effect does not correctly [clean up](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#so-what-about-cleanup), you should add a `removeEventListener` too.

```
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", logNum);
```

Now if you debug this piece of code, you'll notice that the effect triggers on every rerender. That is because a new `logNum` function gets created on every rerender, no matter wether `num` changes or not. To prevent that, you can use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to make the `logNum` reference stable:

```
  const logNum = useCallback(() => console.log(num), [num]);
```

An alternative to all of this would be to use a reference to the [current state](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#swimming-against-the-tide):

```
  const actualNum = useRef(num);

    // that works no matter when and how this is executed
    console.log(actualNum.current);
```